# mysql related items based on following keywords

Tags: mysql

I have this query that works, but not how I want it to.

```
SELECT series.*
     , count(DISTINCT similar.name) as shared_tags 
  FROM series
  JOIN follow 
    ON series.id = follow.series_id 
   AND follow.user_id = '{$user->data['id']}'
  JOIN ( keywords AS this_series INNER JOIN keywords AS similar USING (name) ) ON similar.series_id = follow.series_id
    GROUP BY series.id
    ORDER BY shared_tags DESC LIMIT 8
```

Basically I want it to select all the keywords from series people follow and then recommend other series based on how many keywords match. However the query only selects the series that a user follows.

How do I make it so that it selects series not in following but match the keywords people are following.

Thanks :)

Comment: The query is based on another query which isn't needed in this one. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Proper DDLs and a desired result might help

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor Read the tag description(s)